# Core Data [Entity length]:

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm working on an app and it's my first time using Core Data and everything was going smooth until I hit a rock.

Here is my stack trace

```
2015-07-20 23:39:41.030 Small Things[290:21425] -[Entity1 length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13769ecb0
2015-07-20 23:39:41.031 Small Things[290:21425] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Entity1 length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13769ecb0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x184eaff94 0x199853f2c 0x184eb6cac 0x184eb3c4c 0x184db725c 0x184d97798 0x18a4cce20 0x10005f5f0 0x100063730 0x18a7fdb90 0x18a7fdce8 0x18a7ee890 0x18a802910 0x18a5abe78 0x18a4be4fc 0x189cfad04 0x189cf5920 0x189cf57e0 0x189cf4e80 0x189cf4bd4 0x189cee34c 0x184e66f44 0x184e64cbc 0x184e650ec 0x184d91800 0x18fe1f170 0x18a52a5e8 0x10005f4a0 0x19a08e8b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

and here is the code that caused the problem:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    //Fetch data from persistence
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Entity1"];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest2 = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Entity2"];
    self.arr1 = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil]mutableCopy];
    self.arr2 = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest2 error:nil]mutableCopy];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

I really don't get what's wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you know this is the offending code? Where are you calling `length` on any object?

Comment: That's the point, I'm not calling it anywhere. I was led to believe it was that because after that piece of code it started giving error

Comment: Did you do a full text search?

Comment: I didn't also. All I did was try to fetch the results from core data and add them to the table view.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this error is about the entity name you're using is not kind of `NSString`, so the code believes that you are using some type else (not `NSString`).

But it could be also, that is the model associated with the context’s persistent store coordinator does not contain an entity named `Entity1`.

Comment: I do believe it's of NSString kind and I'm 100% positive the context contains the entity